# Displaying UIButtons separated by UILabels in multiple lines

Tags: iphone, ios, uibutton, uilabel

I have a problem with displaying `UIButtons` separated by `UILabels`.

In the Facebook app, anyone can 'like' another person's status. The persons who liked the status will then be displayed at the bottom of the status separated by `,` or `and`.

Example:

```
Kalyan,urimi and kalyanurimi likes this
```

And If people who liked this are more than can be shown on one line, then the names are displayed in the next line.

Example:

```
Kalyan, urimi ,kalyanurimi, kalyan,
urimi and kalyan likes this
```

Please help me.

[image: screenshot]

Comment: What you tried ? Add the code in which you are getting the Error !!!

Comment: Can you explain what you are trying to achieve, also are you doing this programmatically or using NIBs or Storyboard, finally can you please post some code of what you have tried so far

Comment: I am using storyboard. Initially I have created a UIButton considering only one user. Later I want to display the multiple usernames. So now I require multiple buttons. But I am not sure that we use label instead of buttons. Is there a way to define a tap action for labels.......

Answer (score 0):

For this you have to use clickable `UILable` see some example

[Tweetlabel](https://www.cocoacontrols.com/controls/iftweetlabel)
[STweetlabel](https://www.cocoacontrols.com/controls/sttweetlabel)
[OHAttributedlabel](https://www.cocoacontrols.com/controls/ohattributedlabel)
[DAAttributedstringutils](https://www.cocoacontrols.com/controls/daattributedstringutils)
[PPLabel](https://www.cocoacontrols.com/controls/pplabel)
[RTLabel](https://www.cocoacontrols.com/controls/rtlabel)
[GLTaplabeldemo](https://www.cocoacontrols.com/controls/gltaplabeldemo)

Now you find the click of any word.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you can create a label with comma separated and call method on tap event on them like bellow.

```
-(void)touchesBegan:(NSSet*)touches withEvent:(UIEvent*)event
{
   UITouch *touch = [touches anyObject];

   if(touch.view.tag == your_label_tag){
       //Do anything here
   }

}
```